# Reading text file value from Azure Blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to read the value of a `.txt` file I have on `azure blob storage`.

My code so far:

```
BlobServiceClient BlobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("connectionstring");
var containerClient = BlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("staging");
var blobClient2 = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient($"myfile.txt");
var date = blobClient2.DownloadAsync().Result;
```

But this returns metadata, how do I get the actual text within the `.txt` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. [Azure Blob storage client library v12 for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet):**

```
var blobClient2 = container.GetBlockBlobClient("test.txt");
BlobDownloadInfo download = blobClient2.Download();
var content = download.Content;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(content))
{
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

[image]

[`BlobDownloadInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobdownloadinfo?view=azure-dotnet) has the content property.

**2. [Azure Blob storage client library v11 for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet-legacy):**

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("StorageConnectionString");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

var content = await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
```

[`DownloadTextAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtextasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) is used for the older version.

Comment: the .Value property seems to be invalid `Extensions.Value<U>(IEnumerable<JToken>)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context`.